# Randomly getting empty output while executing shell command via JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am trying to execute below Linux command via JSch (space check command) using JSch:

```
df -h -P |awk '{print $6"  "$4}' |awk '{ if ($1 == "/On_Demand") {print}}' | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{ if ($1 ~ /M/) {print ($1*1)} else if($1 ~ /G/) {print ($1*1024)} else if($1 ~ /T/) {print ($1*1024*1024)} else if($1==0) {print ($1*1)} else if($1 ~ /K/) {print ($1/1024)} else {print ("-1")}}'
```

Backup command:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/ora/home;export ORACLE_SID=sid;/U01/NEW_DEMO/path/to/ora/home/bin/expdp username/password directory=ON_DEMAND schemas=xyz dumpfile=expdp_xyz.dmp logfile=xyz.log;tail -n 1 /On_Demand/xyz.log
```

Code to read output:

```
public String getOutput() {
    LOGGER.debug("[getOutput]");
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    InputStream in = null;
    if (channel != null && channel.isConnected()) {
        try {
            in = channel.getInputStream();
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0)
                        break;
                    output.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    LOGGER.debug("[getOutput] Channel is closed, so breaking while loop with exit code: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            channel.disconnect();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Channel is disconnected");
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

The issue is, when I try to read the command output, many times I get the free space, but there are times I get no output.
When the SSH class is called again (like 2 or 3 times, where in a new session is established) to fire the same command, I get the output (which is strange).

The same issue is occurring in another functionality where I fire a command to take backup of an Oracle schema and when I try to read the log file generated by Oracle (both backup and tail commands are fired at once, semi colon separated), I get no output, but the log file is there. Multiple attempts to fire the same backup command gives me output.

This is a huge problem occurring in my tool since a month.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a race condition in your code.

The channel runs it own thread to read the data. The thread can receive data after you test `in.available()`, but before you test `channel.isConnected()`. While the like-hood may be low, it perfectly explains the random behavior you are experiencing.

See how the [official `Exec.java` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html) re-tests the `in.available()` again in the `channel.isClosed()` block.

```
byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
while(true){
  while(in.available()>0){
    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
    if(i<0)break;
    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
  }
  if(channel.isClosed()){
    if(in.available()>0) continue; 
    System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
    break;
  }
  try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
}
```