# Using 'become' command in Java JSch program to access a restricted directory

Tags: java, shell, unix, ssh, jsch

Working with Unix server... My requirement is to read the name of the file that is there at `/a/b/c/node01/d.ear` location on a Unix server and I have do the same through a java program. The problem is that the directory `a` is a restricted directory and is accessible only to certain users. On the Unix side, I first issue a `become` command like `become a`, then supply the password and then using `cd` command, I reach the `d.ear` directory and then get to see the name of the file.

How do I do all of this via a Java program?

I don't mind if my Java program calls a shell script that accesses the restricted directory and then reach `d.ear` and fetch the name of the file and returns the same to the java program. Do we have a way of doing this? Maybe issuing the become command inside the script which is called from the Java program and the password which is asked after become command is supplied as a parameter while calling the script???

Is this approach doable? I am very new to Unix commands and JSch library. Kindly provide the code or any other alternate solutions...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As [I have suggested you already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44716307/850848#comment76420132_44716498), your `become` command seems to behave the same way (from an interface/API point of view) as common *nix `su` or `sudo`.

So, use the same solution as for those. There are many questions on Stack Overflow covering use of `su`/`sudo` with JSch.

There's even an official JSch example `Sudo.java`:
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html

In short:

- Execute `become` command
- Feed a password to its input
- Assuming the `become` starts a new shell (as `su` or `sudo` do), you feed the commands to be executed in the elevated environment to `become` input (the same was as the password).

Comment: Show us your code + Show us a matching interactive SSH session transcript.

Comment: The code on the java side is same as mentioned on the link that you gave : "http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html"

Comment: You have to replace the `sudo` with `become` in the `setCommand` call!

Comment: Replaced like : ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("become -S -p '' "+command);



The input supplied on getting the prompt "Enter command, execed with sudo", "printenv SUDO_USER" is :


 become cussdv01

O/P is : 



Usage: become <account>

Or you can do:
    become -list 

This will list accounts you have access to on this server

exit-status: 1

Comment: Come on! Think a bit! This is not, what you are doing in shell! You are doing something like: `(ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("become cussdv01");` I cannot be exact, as your comments are hardly readable. Particularly it's not clear what are individual lines.